# If an HTML element has a listener, what happens to the listener after that element is removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title states, If I have a jQuery listener tied to an HTML element, and then delete the HTML element from the DOM using jQuery what happens?

```
<div id="eventDiv> ... </div>


$('#eventDiv').click(function() {
    // event handling code here
 });
```

then what happens to the listener when I do

```
 $('#eventDiv').remove();
```

Also, what happens if you don't use jQuery and use document.removeChild()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), `remove()` calls a function called `cleanData` which calls `jQuery.event.remove` or `jQuery.removeEvent` (this seems to be an internal function). These methods eventually call `unbind()` which removes any event listeners for the DOM element that you are deleting.

Comment: Sweet, so does document.removeChild result in any listener cleanup?

Comment: @stevebot [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) says that the removed element remains in memory (you get a reference to the removed element). Eventually it probably gets garbage-collected (just speculating), which may or may not remove the listener; you'd have to look at the source :)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to be aware of as I'm dealing with a mix of YUI, prototype, JQuery and straight javascript in my app lol